# In contract state is it okay to use regular u128s, or should the Uint128 wrapper be used?

Tags: archway-network, cosmwasm

I was under the impression that the Uint* wrappers were used generally for client-side interaction points only but am I mistaken? I am create a state where I need to store an unsigned integer and I opted to use **u128** but then I wondered if it was more ideal to use the **Uin128** wrapper at all times instead of **u128** directly.

```rust
use cosmwasm_std::{
    to_binary, Binary, Deps, DepsMut, Env, MessageInfo, Response, StdError, StdResult,
};
use cosmwasm_storage::{singleton, singleton_read, ReadonlySingleton, Singleton};

const CONFIG_KEY: &[u8] = b"config";

pub struct State {
    pub count: u128,
}

pub fn instantiate(
    deps: DepsMut,
    _env: Env,
    _info: MessageInfo,
    _msg: Binary,
) -> StdResult<Response> {
    let state = State { count: 0 };
    singleton(deps.storage, CONFIG_KEY).save(&state)?;
    Ok(Response::default())
}

pub fn execute(
    deps: DepsMut,
    _env: Env,
    _info: MessageInfo,
    _msg: Binary,
) -> StdResult<Response> {
    let mut state: State = singleton_read(deps.storage, CONFIG_KEY).load()?;
    state.count += 1;
    singleton(deps.storage, CONFIG_KEY).save(&state)?;
    Ok(Response::default())
}

pub fn query(deps: Deps, _env: Env, _msg: Binary) -> StdResult<Binary> {
    let state: State = singleton_read(deps.storage, CONFIG_KEY).load()?;
    Ok(to_binary(&state)?)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The choice between **u128** and **Uint128** (from the **cosmwasm_std** crate) for storage state often leans towards **Uint128** due to its additional methods and safety features. Uint128 provides overflow safe arithmetic operations. If you use raw u128 you would need to ensure safety yourself, potentially leading to critical contract bugs if not handled properly. Uint128 wrapper is also great when handling serialization and deserialization for storage.